# Where/How is the Azure FTP Host created/controlled for web sites?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

Is the ftp host unique to a subscription or something like service plan? I'm just curious regarding what is controlling the assignment of the ftp host. In our case all app services regardless of app service plan, location or subscription appear to have the same host. Logging into an ftp location is done by \

Answer (score 0):

The FTP host name is the same for all Web Apps in the same scale unit, regardless of user and subscription. When you say it is the same regardless of **location**, I believe you are mistaken, as that simply cannot be (please compare them carefully).

Note that the Web App name is part of the user name (YourApp\YourName), which is how it knows what app is being connected to.